# Read data from mdb file with php

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access, server

I'm reading a mdb file using PHP with a local server like this:

```
<?php
    $myapp = new \COM("word.application");
    $conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection") or die("Oops!");
    $conn->Open("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\admin.mdb","","password");
    $data = $conn->Execute("SELECT * FROM TFTemp17");
    print "<TABLE border='1'>print "<tr>";
    print $data[4];
    print "</tr>";
    echo "</TABLE>";
?>
```

In this mbd file a have a table with rows and columns, so until I'm reading just the first row and the column I want, but I don't know how to read the second row. What I want is to read a certain column on a certain row (not only the first), how could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through the recordset pulled from your ADO execute line. See [PHP COM](http://php.net/manual/en/class.com.php) manual:

```
$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection") or die("Oops!");
$conn->Open("DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\admin.mdb","","password");
$data = $conn->Execute("SELECT * FROM TFTemp17");

echo "<TABLE border='1'>";
echo "<tr>";

$num_columns = $data->Fields->Count();
while (!$data->EOF) {
    for ($i=0; $i < $num_columns; $i++) {
        echo "<td>".$data->Fields($i)->value."</td>";
    }
    $data->MoveNext();
}

echo "</tr>";
echo "</TABLE>";

$data->Close();
$conn->Close();

$data = null;
$conn = null;
```

Comment: I am getting this error. please guide. thanks "Data source name not found and no default driver specified i"

Comment: @MindRoasterMir - You may have the newer version: `Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)`. In Powershell terminal, run [`Get-OdbcDriver`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/wdac/get-odbcdriver?view=win10-ps) to see all installed drivers.

Comment: thanks I checked it did not tell me the version. By the way I have Office 2019 installed, does it install with it ? And what to do if I have a newer version ?